# Linear subspace as an affine variety

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

I saw the following description in a book of Algebraic Geometry, as example of affine variety.

> Let $l_1,...,l_k $ be independent linear forms in $X_1,...,X_n$. Let $a_1,...,a_k \in \mathbb{C} $.Then $X = V(l_1-a_1,...,l_k-a_k)$ is a variety, called a *linear subspace* of  $\mathbb{C}^n$ of dimension $n-k$.

I think, it is true when $(a_1,...,a_k)=(0,...,0)$ according to linear algebra, but when $(a_1,...,a_k) \neq (0,...,0)$, $X$ is not a linear subspace because $X$ has not $(0,...,0)$. and I think X is a translate of a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Is my opinion true? or What is the author's intention? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are thinking of $\mathbb{C}^n$ as a vector space, the author is thinking of it as an *affine* space. An affine space carries an action of a vector space (translation). An linear subspace of an affine space is one that is an orbit for a sub-vector space of this vector space.

Comment: I assumed "a linear subspace of C^n" means a vector subspace of C^n but, I realized that author saying it is an affine subspace thanks to your answer.